# ASP.NET Core GDPR EU cookie sample project bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, google-analytics

To satisfy the EU cookie/GDPR laws, I am trying to set a variable to true or false to hide or show Google Analytics tracking code in the `<head>` of my ASP.NET Core 2 site (uses MVC) depending on if a user clicks `Agree` or not. I assume this is the best way to do this for Google Analytics/Tag Manager? Any ideas on the best way to implement this for Google Analytics would be appreciated. Anyway, by default, the value should be set to false and Google Analytics should be disabled until the user explicitly accepts.

I am following the official [ASP.NET Core guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

However, the problem comes when I open up the GDPR [sample code](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/live/aspnetcore/security/gdpr/sample). I think there might be a bug?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open and run the project
2. Click `Consent` > `Grant` On the Home Page. You can also click `Accept` in the box at the top of the page.
3. On the Home Page, notice that `Has` is still false, as is `Can track`. Shouldn't these values change?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this without using ASP.NET, just using GTM.

1. Create a 1st party cookie variable
   [image]
2. Create a trigger of page view type, fires on some pages with the condition "cookie=true"
   [image]
3. Then for all your tracking tags that used "all pages" change it to this new trigger
   [image]